# How to get the XMLHttpResponse send data in my views.py?

Tags: python, django, xmlhttprequest

In the template I send data use XMLHttpResponse.

My code is below:

```
...
<input type="button" value="ajax1" onclick="ajax1()">


<script>

    function ajax1(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/ajax1/', true);  
        xhr.send("name=root;pwd=123");  // send data
    }

</script>
```

But how can I in the `views.py` to receive the data?

In my `views.py`:

```
def ajax1(request):
    print request.GET.get('name'), request.GET.get('pwd') # all is None.
    return HttpResponse('ajax1')
```

You see, I use `request.GET.get(param_key)` to get the data failed.

How to get the XMLHttpResponse send data in my views.py?

Answer (score 0):

You should know the XMLHttpResponse's `send()` method is send request body.
Your request method is GET. so you can not pass the data.

You try to use post method to pass the data like this:

```
function ajax1(){
    var xhr = getXHR();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){  
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {   

            console.log(xhr.responseText); 

            var json_obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(json_obj);

        }
    }; 

    xhr.open("POST", "/ajax1/", true);   
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset-UTF-8"); // add the request header

    xhr.send("name=root; pwd=123;");  // send data
}
```